# On click event only fire once while having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl

I have a notification system that generates all of an user's notifications into a table in my html along with a bunch of rows like these:

```
<td class = "archive-button" data-notice_id = "<%= $notice->notice_id()%>">Archive</td>
```

I then have a js script that runs everytime a "archive-button" is pressed:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
    var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
    var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
    var archived_notice = 'tr.notification-' + notice_id;

    $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}).done(function(){
        $(archived_notice).css("background" , "#F2F2F2");
        $('#num-posts').html(parseInt($('#num-posts').html(), 10) -1);
    });
});
```

My question is: how do i make it so each button can only trigger the event once? Each  class is the same as "archive-button" so when I do .one('clicl') it disables all my other  that hasn't been clicked yet. I can retrieve the notice_id from perl and insert it into each  tag when they're generated but I still can't reference that in my js script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `data` attributes as you have used to store `notice-id`, but now as a flag:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function() {
    if ($(this).data("clicked") !== true) {
        $(this).data("clicked", true);

        var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
        var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
        var archived_notice = 'tr.notification-' + notice_id;

        $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}).done(function() {
            $(archived_notice).css("background" , "#F2F2F2");
            $('#num-posts').html(parseInt($('#num-posts').html(), 10) -1);
        });
    }
});
```

Note: You should use a *real* button(`input` or `a`) instead of a `td` tag acting as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your listeners to actual table cells as opposed to `document`:

```
$( 'td.archive-button' ).one( 'click', function(){
     var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');

     // etc....
});
```

When done in this way, each cell will get it's own click listener, thus effectively removing the need to store any current state.